# How to use Ubuntu font with TeXLive 2012?

Tags: fonts, installing, texlive, ubuntu

I really like the `Ubuntu` sans font, I want it be the section and title font as a replacement of Linux-Biolinum?

With Ubuntu 12.04 LTS + Texlive 2012,  how to figure this out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `XeTeX`, it comes with TeXLive 2012 and can use any system font automatically.

Here is a MWE that should work on Ubuntu. Copy to a new file, save as `test.tex` and compile it with `xelatex test.tex` from your console:

```
% !TEX TS-program = xelatex
% !TEX encoding =UTF-8 Unicode

\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec} % Allows font customization
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont{Ubuntu} % Main document font

\begin{document}

A one-line test.

\end{document}
```

Comment: Xelatex error `The font "Ubuntu Regular" cannot be found.`

Comment: Try `\setmainfont{Ubuntu}`. You have to look for the font's name in the system directory. Sorry, I got to no Ubuntu machine to check right now...

Comment: Also, see this longer explanation for Lyx: http://askubuntu.com/a/8331/78383

Comment: @KOF: Fine! If my answer works for you, you may tick the solved button so everyone sees that it's been solved.